# Why aren't all fields displayed in the following HTML code with grid?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Only the pink field is displayed in the browser. I want to implement a responsive Web Design with the method Mobile First.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
      <style>
          body, html{
              height: 100%;
              display: grid;
          }
    
          @media screen and (min-width: 900px) { /* greater than or equal 900px */
              grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
              grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
              grid-template-areas:
          "red red red"
          "green blue pink";
          }
        .redArea { grid-area: red; }
        .greenArea{ grid-area: green; }
        .blueArea { grid-area: blue; }
        .pinkArea { grid-area: pink; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="redArea" style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="greenArea" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="blueArea" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="pinkArea" style="background-color: pink"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMZV3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that what's inside your media query isn't a rule, just a set of declarations. You probably meant to apply your grid template to the body element, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
      <style>
          body, html{
              height: 100%;
              display: grid;
          }
    
          @media screen and (min-width: 400px) { 
            /* greater than or equal 400px (min-width reduced for
               demonstration purposes) */
              body {
                  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
                  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
                  grid-template-areas:
                      "red red red"
                      "green blue pink";
              }
          
              .redArea { grid-area: red; }
              .greenArea{ grid-area: green; }
              .blueArea { grid-area: blue; }
              .pinkArea { grid-area: pink; }
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="redArea" style="background-color: red;"></div>
    <div class="greenArea" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="blueArea" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="pinkArea" style="background-color: pink"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

More interesting, is why you can only see the pink box and why is it in the bottom right quadrant.

In fact, all four boxes are in the right quadrant, the pink one is last, so it is on top and covers the other boxes.

As for why the bottom right quadrant, the specification isn't all that clear, but I think it goes like this¹: Because the grid-area names aren't defined, (because the media query is invalid) the names each identify a grid area in the implicit grid. The first grid line both horizontally and vertically is part of the explicit grid so is skipped, then the first unmatched grid area (i.e. "red") adds one grid-line in the implicit grid in both axes to start the grid cell and another one to end the grid cell.

Then the other unmatched grid-line names (i.e. "green", "blue", and "pink") can reuse the same grid lines (since they are all in the implicit grid) and so both axes end up with three grid lines. The divs are then all placed between the second and third grid lines in both axes, and since the available area is divided equally between the grid tracks, it result in the four divs all being placed in the same grid cell in the bottom right quadrant.

---

<sub>¹ I'm not wholly convinced by this explanation. If there's anyone who knows better, please correct me.</sub>